# Is there a way to log how many instances of something are created in javascript?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome, garbage-collection

Right now in some javascript code I am writing, the profiler shows that garbage collection is taking up a lot of time. I was wondering if there was a way to see exactly why so much time was spent with garbage collection. Any suggestions for some good chrome or firefox plugins or debugging tools to help me do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Chrome Developer tools have built in support for memory profiling. This allows you to profile memory allocations and garbage collection:

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-memory-profiling

As you can see, they show you the count for each object.